# Will beq work in this situation?

Tags: assembly, mips32

If I have two empty registers `$1`and `$2`, and I want to jump to another one `$dest`, will the `beq` instruction work or do I have to use other instructions? I'm doubtful because `beq` actually checks if two registers have the same value but is "empty" considered a value?

Comment: Are `$1` and `$2` the usual GP MIPS registers? Because in such case they cannot be empty (Did you mean zeroed?), just like a number cannot be empty.

Comment: Yes I meant zeroed, that means that the beq can read if two registers are both zero?

Comment: Yes, of course.